# Get the iDevice system language to issue an IF

Tags: ios, swift, nslocale

I'm trying to get the system language ofrom the iDevice of the user, basically I want 1 image if it'S in french, and another if it's english

any ideas ?

My code (that doesn't display the image either way)

```
let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0] as String

if preferredLanguage == "en" {
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
} else if preferredLanguage == "fr" {
    navigationItem.titleView = imageViewFR
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Also, "uk" is not a valid language.

Comment: sorry meant it to show "fr" i corrected it, and the image is not showing. it's the UINavigationBar Title that i'm changing, no IF it's good. With the IF condition it doesn't work

Comment: What value are you getting for `preferredLanguage`?

Comment: *doesn't work* isn't a sufficient description.

Comment: the value i'm getting is en-US

Comment: NSLocale.preferredLanguages [can return a variety of identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2418/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016588-CH1-LANGUAGE_IDENTIFIERS_IN_IOS_9)... `"en" != "en-US"`

Comment: ok, is there anything other than NSLocale I can use ? to put simply I want it to be another image only if the system language is french, else I want it to be then english image

Comment: Try getting the `NSLocaleLanguageCode` value from the current locale instead of looking at the list of preferred languages.

Comment: here's my new constant : `let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String` which returns `en` (in this case) but the code inside the if statement doesn't display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write (error-prone) just to localize an image. Just put the image files into the appropriate localization folder in your app bundle — then APIs like `NSBundle.pathForResource` and `UIImage(named:)` will automatically load the image corresponding to the user's preferred language. (And if the images for different languages have different dimensions, you don't need separate image views — just use Auto Layout.)

See [Localized Resources in Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW7) and [Adding Additional Resources You Want to Localize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW17) in Apple's docs.

Comment: thanks a lot the link especially was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out @rmaddy was right, here's the answer

```
    let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode) as! String

    if preferredLanguage == "fr" {
        navigationItem.titleView = imageViewFR
    } else {
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
```

to get the system language we need to use NSLocale.currentLocale() then it worked ! thanks @rmaddy

Comment: That's the wrong way to handle localized images on iOS. See @rickster's answer for the right way.